# Microsoft graph access token error AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get an access token from Microsoft Graph API, after getting the code successfully.

Writing the code according to this training link:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user

When i call the following POST call, i get the error:
**"AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'"**

This is the POST Call (using PHP):

```
$clientId = "XXXXXXXXX-ded0-4150-80c6-37e326ff6b26";
$clientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXuakCZYA701@#!";
$responseUri = "https%3A%2F%2Fmyserver.mydomain.com%2Fsugarcrmmaintest%2Fresponse.php";
$postUrl = "/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";     
$hostname = "login.microsoftonline.com";
$fullurl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";

$headers = array(
    "POST " . $postUrl . " HTTP/1.1",
    "Host: " . $hostname,
    "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
);

$post_params = array(
    "client_id" => $clientId,                    
    "scope" => "offline_access%20calendars.readwrite",
    "code" => "XXXXXXXXXXADX8GCi6Js6SK82TsD2Pb7rKYvnsfWlNknact_Tq6rBJWkoiY5k0W8CfvQRwO-TwwrgBlMxpOel5uE4gT0k6LCY4u_aZxbPhj5u5ATDT1AJbXKdL39IuidFWoEoZ2i3awf7LYupb_eO-gI4wEVI2JYl2VoJ23tKwnHQVUWlRBxexYIEkzwE0U6EYqk5RKnm4UGfe1oukoi0BI5vHUpEtJ_J7Me-r4_8oeRfz1BHDwPv_HOXEw0rsmjHG_VyzVEjdsiU7RVOQBzxY1Ks79CcqpHPTPimSZLPqg4-jByURQryr7ueRMpgeys8kJxDiZnh9tw0QULjs0ZbrPBAhE7CeeHtBK0cGbu0zFY5I428BwtylIEqN-bQZc7Y5RRFBFnSYSs8nYMCM61YkXpRXmhPhxFM583o6wwUTO6ZIGmj99GG1j3Ys7XmC3Tn6xpOM8wEMKmcVkcHL4aH0EfO-heG6_59dpBSuonBPXU6DPa7axV89rHF-6A9vXvEHO6pwZFXXJlp1COTo8r4LuT0Q-gbcAx7wlkepdfGf0gHQcRiYWe953_rwPyRDfXmZnZEgOPUAzHJxvbVuLuI24xVohxjk73wCWpPFgM9lDN0bt40DsMdbICb28LE2cdc9TIspIdVj-aO7cEwMZQsgULzEAPcqXTRJpVEeLgUbMTjLChjwldGAHQyoYcPrbCWHP2oOnOjrQMgAA",
    "redirect_uri" => $responseUri,
    "grant_type" => "authorization_code",   
    "client_secret" => $clientSecret,
);

$curl = curl_init($fullurl);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);


$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

i read similar posts in this forum, but it didn't solve it...

can anyone help? :)

Comment: From reading your link.  It looks like the grant_type is the authorization code that you were suppose to receive from step 2.

Comment: just remove `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);` and then try once

Comment: @Rodniko please encode your request `http_build_query ( $post_params )`

Comment: Thank you PHP dev i needed to use "http_build_query" before the post call. the correct code is:   $post_params = array(
 "client_id" => $clientId,         
 "scope" => "offline_access calendars.readwrite",
   "code" => "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX82TsD2Pb7r20os0ctl7jp19x2LverW0UT8qSnCpfAfo0F3sm7p8Q8h_ZUkX4PkAaxNKNLd-",
   "redirect_uri" => "https://myserver.mydomain.com/sugarcrmmaintest/response.php",
   "grant_type" => "authorization_code", 
   "client_secret" => $clientSecret,

       );

  $encodedPostParams = http_build_query ( $post_params );